# Describe the continuous homomorphisms of $(\mathbb{R}, +) \to (\mathbb{C} - \{0\}, \cdot)$

Tags: topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

The maps in question all have the form:

(1) $x \mapsto e^{ax}$ with $a$ any complex number.

These maps include the

(1) The real-valued exponential maps, $x \mapsto b^x$

(2) The unit circle-valued 'wrap around' maps, $x \mapsto e^{ipx}$

(3) The 'spiral' maps, like $x  \mapsto e^{(1+i)x}$

Note that you can always use the complex conjugate automorphism after the initial mapping, getting another such map. But the result can still be put in the form of (1).

Using the proof argument from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/620495/432081) on isomorphisms and cyclicality, and the fact that the kernel of continuous homomorphisms are closed, I think this is it.

Also, do the images of these maps give us all the locally compact and connected proper subgroups of $(\mathbb{C} - \{0\}, \cdot)$?

Let me know if I am missing any maps and if there are any 'go to' spots in the literature focusing on this question.

Comment: $x  \mapsto e^{(1+i)x}$ (and others, but all are similar)

Comment: Thanks - looks like I missed the 'spiral' subgroups!
Will edit them into the question.

Comment: All of these are of the form $x \mapsto e^{ax}$ for some complex constant $a$.  That's it.

Comment: As for the last question consider the set $Z_n$ of the $n$th roots of unit of $\Bbb C$. Each is a proper subgroup but (for $n > 1$) is not connected.

Comment: And for motivation for a unified expression, note that the maps in (2) can be written as $x \mapsto e^{cx}$, where respectively $c = \log b$.

Comment: @travis OK, (of course) - adding in 'connected' adjective.

Comment: @gedgar Is this easily proved?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** The fact that classes (2) and (3) really are homomorphisms relies on the property that $$\exp (ax + ay) = \exp (ax) \exp (ay),$$ respectively for real and imaginary $a$. On the other hand, the identity holds for all complex $a$.

**Edit** The question has been edited since my original answer. In particular, the 'spiral' maps of the added class (4) are exactly the maps $x \mapsto \exp(ax)$, where $\textrm{Re}\, a \neq 0$ and $\textrm{Im}\, a \neq 0$.

Comment: I think you goofed on $\exp (ax + ay) = \exp a \exp (x + y)$.

Comment: It did look fishy, and so I went with (1 + i) comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch:

Recall the results and techniques found in [$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233122/simple-classification-proof-of-all-continuous-homomorphism-from-the-reals-under). We also have the natural 'projection':

$P: \mathbb{C} / \{0\} \rightarrow S^1$, which is a continuous homomorphism.

So if $f: (\mathbb{R}, +) \to (\mathbb{C} - \{0\}, \cdot)$ is given we can analyze $P \circ f$ and use polar coordinates. By so doing we can show that, once we know $f(1)$ there is only one possible continuous homomorphism. So, indeed, the exponential functiions,

$x \mapsto e^{ax}$
are precisely the answer to this question.